# Change PivotHeaderItem Style in UWP?

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to change the PivotHeaderItem Style of Pivot. So, I googled and found some code from some blog. But I didn't understand, how the modified PivotHeaderItem style is assigned to the Pivot.
They just put the PivotHeaderItem style in Page.Resources.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemThemeFontWeight}" />
        <Setter Property="CharacterSpacing" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemCharacterSpacing}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemMargin}" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="48" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Margin="10,0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style x:Key="BaseContentPresenterStyle" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="XamlAutoFontFamily" />
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
                                <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                                <Setter Property="LineStackingStrategy" Value="MaxHeight" />
                                <Setter Property="TextLineBounds" Value="Full" />
                                <Setter Property="OpticalMarginAlignment" Value="TrimSideBearings" />
                            </Style>
                            <Style x:Key="BodyContentPresenterStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseContentPresenterStyle}" TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontFamily}" />
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemThemeFontWeight}" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemFontSize}" />
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Unselected" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" To="UnselectedLocked" />
                                    <VisualTransition From="UnselectedLocked" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.33" To="Unselected" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlDisabledBaseMediumLowBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedLocked">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                                                         To="{ThemeResource PivotHeaderItemLockedTranslation}" />
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)"
                                                         To="0" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Red" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="UnselectedPressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedPressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltBaseMediumHighBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Grid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Border"
                                BorderBrush="Gray"
                                BorderThickness="2"
                                CornerRadius="20">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                              FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}"
                                              FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                              FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}">
                                <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="ContentPresenterTranslateTransform" />
                                </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Pivot x:Name="rootPivot" Title="PIVOT TITLE">
        <PivotItem Header="Pivot Item 1">
            <!--  Pivot content goes here  -->
            <TextBlock Text="Content of pivot item 1." />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="Pivot Item 2">
            <!--  Pivot content goes here  -->
            <TextBlock Text="Content of pivot item 2." />
        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="Pivot Item 3">
            <!--  Pivot content goes here  -->
            <TextBlock Text="Content of pivot item 3." />
        </PivotItem>
    </Pivot>
</Grid>
```

Any one explain, How the styles inside the <Page.Resources> is assigned to Pivot Element inside the grid automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to apply a style that is placed in the resource to
a control.

1. Implicitly. You just need to specify only a **TargetType** for the Style.
2. Explicitly. You need to specifying a **TargetType** and an **x:Key** attribute for the Style. After that, you also need to set the target control's `Style property` with a **{StaticResource} markup extension**. In the **{StaticResource} markup extension**, you could refer to the Style with the **x:Key** attribute you defined.

If a style contains the **x:Key** attribute, you can only apply it to a control by setting the Style property of the control to the keyed style. In contrast, when the xaml is compiled, a style without an **x:Key** attribute is automatically applied to every control of its target type unless that control has an explicit style setting.

**Update:**

To make the style only work for one **Pivot control**, you could put the style in the `Pivot.Resources`. Like the following code:

```
      <Pivot x:Name="rootPivot" Title="PIVOT TITLE" >
            <Pivot.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="PivotHeaderItem">
                    ......
                    ......
            </Pivot.Resources>

            <PivotItem Header="Pivot Item 1" >

                <!--  Pivot content goes here  -->
                <TextBlock Text="Content of pivot item 1." />
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem Header="Pivot Item 2">
                <!--  Pivot content goes here  -->
                <TextBlock Text="Content of pivot item 2." />
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem Header="Pivot Item 3">
                <!--  Pivot content goes here  -->
                <TextBlock Text="Content of pivot item 3." />
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
```

Comment: ok fine, I understand. But, I need to explicitly assign the PivotHeaderItem style to pivot. How to do that? I didn't find any property for style in Pivot for setting PivotHeaderItemStyle. Is there any way?

Comment: @PremKumarShanmugam what's the behavior you want to get? Apply different header item styles to different header items in one Pivot control? Or do you want to keep the style only works for one Pivot control?

Comment: I want to apply different item styles to different header Items in one pivot control !!

Comment: @PremKumarShanmugam It is impossible to do that. Only way is to overwrite the header template.

Comment: Or what if I want to keep the style only works for one Pivot control?How to do it?

Comment: Yes, as @Anonymous mentioned, you might need to overwrite the header template if you want to have different pivot header items. If you want to apply one style only to work for one Pivot, you could put the `Style` in the resource of the target pivot control. I'll update my answer to show it clearly.

Comment: yeah thanks!.But, If my pivot object was created in C# and PivotHeaderItem Style is in resources.xaml . How to assign PivotHeaderItem style to Pivot in c#? I didn't find any property in pivot for that?

Comment: I have to say no. This is the same as the question of why you can't apply different styles for different PivotHeaderItems. We can't assign the style directly to the PivotHeaderItem.